# gitlab ci command convertto-securestring get The term '=' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, gitlab

When I using gitlab ci to deploy I need to setting IIS Server deploy password

and I using

```
- pwsh -Command $pw= convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String $env:StagePassword
```

and I will get this error

```
=: The term '=' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

but when I using command line on windows server powershell it's can work

so how to fix the error.

Comment: You have to pass your PowerShell command inside double quotes.

Comment: Like this: 
`pwsh -Command "$pw=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $env:StagePassword"`

Comment: Please read the help for `pwsh.exe` by running `pwsh.exe /?` to learn how to call `pwsh.exe` on a command line.

Comment: Your symptom implies that `$pw` was expanded, namely to the _empty string_, BEFORE `pwsh` ever saw its `-Command` arguments. The solution depends on _why_ this expansion took place: Was it GitLab CI itself? Or is the whole `pwsh` command line passed to `/bin/sh`, or even `pwsh` itself?